# not able to see  list template while creating list in moss 2007

Tags: 2007

i uploaded a list template in my home site.
after uploading, i am able to see the uploaded list template in list gallery but when i go to create new list, i am not able to see this list template in option.

please help me to resolve this.

thanx.

Answer (score 1):

List templates are used to create lists, you use Site Templates to create new sites.

Check both galleries (Site and Lists) to ensure you can see your template in there. There may be content approval in the gallery your template it is in, and the file may be checked out, so you might need to check it in.

Comment: true indeed :-D